# go build fails with linker error when trying to compile a raylib project

Tags: go, raylib

I tried reinstalling llvm, go, clang, xcode but nothing. Googling it doesn't seem to bring anything up either.

The code:

```go
package main

import "github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib"

func main() {
    rl.InitWindow(800, 450, "raylib [core] example - basic window")

    rl.SetTargetFPS(60)

    for !rl.WindowShouldClose() {
        rl.BeginDrawing()

        rl.ClearBackground(rl.RayWhite)

        rl.DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, rl.LightGray)

        rl.EndDrawing()
    }

    rl.CloseWindow()
}
```

Output of `go env`:

```
GO111MODULE="off"
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/dara/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/dara/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/dara/.local/share/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/dara/.local/share/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.3/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/l1/bymjznz5677dy5_mb5x102pr0000gn/T/go-build3427704156=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Output of `go build`:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_objc_msgSend$IBeamCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$UTF8String", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$activateIgnoringOtherApps:", referenced from:
      _glfwCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformFocusWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwShowWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwFocusWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addItem:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addItemWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addObserver:selector:name:object:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addRepresentation:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$addTrackingArea:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$alphaValue", referenced from:
      _glfwGetWindowOpacity in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowOpacity in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$array", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView validAttributesForMarkedText] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$arrayWithObjects:count:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView keyDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$arrowCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView cursorUpdate:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$backingScaleFactor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView viewDidChangeBackingProperties] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$bitmapData", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$bounds", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$bundleWithPath:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$buttonNumber", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView otherMouseDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView otherMouseUp:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$bytes", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$center", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$classNamed:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$clearColor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$clearCurrentContext", referenced from:
      _makeContextCurrentNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$close", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$closedHandCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$containsObject:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$contentRectForFrameRect:", referenced from:
      _glfwGetWindowPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$convertRectToBacking:", referenced from:
      _glfwGetMonitorContentScale in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitorContentScale in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwGetFramebufferSize in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetFramebufferSize in 000002.o
      _glfwGetWindowContentScale in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowContentScale in 000002.o
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend$convertRectToScreen:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWindowHovered in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$count", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$crosshairCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$currentApplication", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$currentEvent", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView insertText:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$declareTypes:owner:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$defaultCenter", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$deltaX", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView mouseMoved:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$deltaY", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView mouseMoved:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$deminiaturize:", referenced from:
      _glfwRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformRestoreWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$deviceDescription", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$distantFuture", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$distantPast", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$draggingLocation", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$draggingPasteboard", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$fileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$flushBuffer", referenced from:
      _swapBuffersNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$frame", referenced from:
      __glfwCenterCursorInContentArea in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowSize in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      _glfwSetInputMode in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetCursorPos in 000002.o
      _glfwGetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend$frameRectForContentRect:", referenced from:
      __glfwInputMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowFrameSize in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowPos in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize in 000002.o
      _glfwGetWindowFrameSize in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$frameRectForContentRect:styleMask:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$generalPasteboard", referenced from:
      _glfwSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView insertText:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$getValues:forParameter:", referenced from:
      _swapBuffersNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$hasPreciseScrollingDeltas", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView scrollWheel:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$hide", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView cursorUpdate:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView mouseEntered:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$infoDictionary", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithAttributedString:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithAttributes:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateContextNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bitmapFormat:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithFormat:shareContext:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateContextNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithGlfwWindow:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithImage:hotSpot:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithRect:options:owner:userInfo:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithSize:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithString:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithTitle:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$interpretKeyEvents:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView keyDown:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isEqualToString:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isFinishedLaunching", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isKeyWindow", referenced from:
      _glfwSetInputMode in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorMode in 000002.o
      _glfwSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWindowFocused in 000002.o
      _glfwGetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isMiniaturized", referenced from:
      _glfwRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwGetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWindowIconified in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isOpaque", referenced from:
      _glfwGetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformFramebufferTransparent in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView isOpaque] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isVisible", referenced from:
      _glfwGetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWindowVisible in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$isZoomed", referenced from:
      _glfwRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwMaximizeWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformMaximizeWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwGetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWindowMaximized in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResize:] in 000002.o
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend$keyCode", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView keyDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView flagsChanged:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView keyUp:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$keyWindow", referenced from:
      ____glfwPlatformInit_block_invoke in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$layer", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$length", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView hasMarkedText] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView markedRange] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView insertText:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$locationInWindow", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView mouseMoved:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$mainBundle", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$makeCurrentContext", referenced from:
      _makeContextCurrentNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$makeFirstResponder:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowDecorated in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$makeKeyAndOrderFront:", referenced from:
      _glfwCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformFocusWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwShowWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwFocusWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$miniaturize:", referenced from:
      _glfwIconifyWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformIconifyWindow in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResignKey:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$miniwindowTitle", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$modifierFlags", referenced from:
      ____glfwPlatformInit_block_invoke in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView mouseDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView mouseUp:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView rightMouseDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView rightMouseUp:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView otherMouseDown:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView otherMouseUp:] in 000002.o
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend$mouse:inRect:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$mouseLocation", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWindowHovered in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      _glfwSetInputMode in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformGetCursorPos in 000002.o
      _glfwGetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$mouseMoved:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView mouseDragged:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView rightMouseDragged:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView otherMouseDragged:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$mutableString", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView unmarkText] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$objectAtIndexedSubscript:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$objectForKeyedSubscript:", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$occlusionState", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidChangeOcclusionState:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$operationNotAllowedCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$orderFront:", referenced from:
      _glfwCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformShowWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwShowWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$orderOut:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwHideWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformHideWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$otherEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:subtype:data1:data2:", referenced from:
      _glfwPostEmptyEvent in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent in 000002.o
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$pathForResource:ofType:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$performSelector:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$performSelector:withObject:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$pointingHandCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$postEvent:atStart:", referenced from:
      _glfwPostEmptyEvent in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent in 000002.o
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$readObjectsForClasses:options:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$registerDefaults:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$registerForDraggedTypes:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$removeMonitor:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$removeObserver:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$removeObserver:name:object:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$removeTrackingArea:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$requestUserAttention:", referenced from:
      _glfwRequestWindowAttention in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformRequestWindowAttention in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$resizeLeftRightCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$resizeUpDownCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$run", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$screens", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$scrollingDeltaX", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView scrollWheel:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$scrollingDeltaY", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView scrollWheel:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$sendEvent:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in 000002.o
      ____glfwPlatformInit_block_invoke in 000002.o
      ...
  "_objc_msgSend$separatorItem", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$set", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView cursorUpdate:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setActivationPolicy:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setAlphaValue:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetWindowOpacity in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowOpacity in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setBackgroundColor:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setCollectionBehavior:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setContentAspectRatio:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowAspectRatio in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setContentMaxSize:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowSizeLimits in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setContentMinSize:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowSizeLimits in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setContentView:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setContentsScale:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView viewDidChangeBackingProperties] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setDelegate:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformDestroyWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setFrame:display:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidDeminiaturize:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setFrameAutosaveName:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setFrameOrigin:", referenced from:
      __glfwInputMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowPos in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowPos in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setHasShadow:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setIgnoresMouseEvents:", referenced from:
      _glfwCreateWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMousePassthrough in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setLayer:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setLevel:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowFloating in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setMainMenu:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setMiniwindowTitle:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setOpaque:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setResizeIncrements:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetWindowAspectRatio in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setRestorable:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setServicesMenu:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setString:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView unmarkText] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setString:forType:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setStyleMask:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowAttrib in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowResizable in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowDecorated in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setSubmenu:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setTabbingMode:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setTitle:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setValues:forParameter:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateContextNSGL in 000002.o
      _swapIntervalNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setView:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateContextNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateContextNSGL in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setWantsLayer:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindowSurface in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$setWindowsMenu:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$sharedApplication", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$standardUserDefaults", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$stop:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$string", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView insertText:replacementRange:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$stringForType:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$stringWithFormat:", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$stringWithUTF8String:", referenced from:
      _glfwSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle in 000002.o
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$types", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$unhide", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformSetCursor in 000002.o
      _updateCursorMode in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView cursorUpdate:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView mouseExited:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$unsignedIntValue", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$update", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResize:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in 000002.o
      -[GLFWContentView updateLayer] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$updateTrackingAreas", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$valueForKey:", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$visibleFrame", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetMonitorWorkarea in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$windowNumber", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWindowHovered in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$windowNumberAtPoint:belowWindowWithWindowNumber:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWindowHovered in 000002.o
  "_objc_msgSend$zoom:", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformRestoreWindow in 000002.o
      _glfwMaximizeWindow in 000002.o
      __glfwPlatformMaximizeWindow in 000002.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: This lacks some information. What's the linux distro? Did you installed all the dependencies as listed [here](https://github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/)?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs It says in the output of go env. It's macos. And yes, I have xcode installed.